# Need to use git in yocto OS

Tags: yocto

I am using the latest yocto by git clone it.

I want to use git in yocto OS.

It seems no 'git' recipe in layers.

Is there an 'git' recipe can be use directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been support for git on the target for ages.

https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/5542/